# Send MongoDB query result as JSON using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongojs

I'm writing an application where I use express, Node.js and MongoDB (using mongojs). I have a module `db.js` and a `server.js`, which have the snippets below.

**db.js**

```
var getUsersByCity = function(city, callback) {
    db.users.find({'city': city}).toArray(function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            callback.json(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**server.js**

```
app.post("/get_users_list", function(req, res) {
    var body = req.body;
    db.getUsersByCity(body.city, res);
});
```

It's working because, as you can see, I'm (probably incorrectly) using `callback.json(data)`, when I should be using `callback(data)`. I think the `db.js` module should not be responsible for sending the response and I should pass `res.json` as the callback to my function.

The problem is: when I do things the way I consider right, I face the following error:

```
path_to_my_app/node_modules/mongojs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:245
        throw message;      
              ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined
    at res.json (path_to_my_app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:189:22)
    at path_to_my_app/db.js:36:13
    at path_to_my_app/node_modules/mongojs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:163:16
    at commandHandler (path_to_my_app/node_modules/mongojs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:706:16)
    at path_to_my_app/node_modules/mongojs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1843:9
    at Server.Base._callHandler (path_to_my_app/node_modules/mongojs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:445:41)
    at path_to_my_app/node_modules/mongojs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:468:18
    at MongoReply.parseBody (path_to_my_app/node_modules/mongojs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)
    at null.<anonymous> (path_to_my_app/node_modules/mongojs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:426:20)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

How to properly send the JSON response without sending the response object to my DB module?

**P.S.** The content of line 36 of `db.js`, when I make the changes, is `callback(data);`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right that `db.js` shouldn't call `res` or even know about it. It's good to keep it separated.

Following this (untested):

**db.js**

```
    var getUsersByCity = function(city, cb) {
        db.users.find({'city': city}).toArray(cb);
    }
```

**server.js**

```
    app.post("/get_users_list", function(req, res) {
        var body = req.body;
        db.getUsersByCity(body.city, function(err, data){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res(err);
            } else {
                console.log(data);
                return res.json(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Two overall problems I see:

First, your db.js file should do something like:

```
callback(err, data);
```

Second, your server.js call should look more like:

```
db.getUsersByCity(body.city, function(err, data){
    if(err){
        res.send(500, "something went wrong");
    }else{
        res.json(data);
    }
});
```

The db.getUsersByCity call is asynchronous because you can't read anything until the database call comes back on it's callback.
I didn't read too much of the error though..  See if that clears things up at all.